# jquery $("<li />")

Tags: jquery

What does:

```
$("<li />")
```

mean in jquery?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#creating-new-elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create's a new (**but empty**) `li` element, similar to `document.createElement("li");`. 
Try doing [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/azVTH/):

```
alert($("<li />")[0]);
```

Essentially, alone it does not do much. To add it to an existing element you could do something like:

```
$("<li />").appendTo("body");
$("<li />").appendTo("#elementId");
```

Answer (score 6):

it's like `document.createElement('li');`

Comment: remember to do something to it. If you don't append(), prepend(), etc. if will do nothing, also, it's faster to use $('element').append('<li />'); Browsers are great at parsing that kind of thing but slow at creating and appending nodes...

Answer (score 2):

It will create a li element, similar to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement

Answer (score 1):

Creates DOM elements (in this case LI) on the fly from the provided string of raw HTML.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Answer (score 1):

By itself nothing but if you add

```
$('<li />').appendTo('body');
```

It will create an li at the end of the body element of your HTML